# I am having a trouble importing the PyDictionary library

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

Basically, I downloaded the library using `pip install PyDictionary` and I made sure it exists by writing the same thing again and this appeared:

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyDictionary in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: goslate in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from PyDictionary) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from bs4->PyDictionary) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4->PyDictionary) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from goslate->PyDictionary) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->PyDictionary) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->PyDictionary) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->PyDictionary) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\ziad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->PyDictionary) (2020.12.5)
```

However, when I try to run this simple program in atom, it says module not found.
This is the program:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary = PyDictionary()

print (dictionary.meaning("indentation"))
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ziad\Desktop\programs\Dictionary.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDictionary'
```

The only way I found to execute the program correctly was by moving the file to the folder where the library exists so that atom can find the library. The weird thing is that the library numpy works perfectly.
I would really like an answer to this problem.

Comment: It's likely that you have multiple versions of Python installed on your device. What command did you use to launch the script that failed? Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: python3 Dictionary.py .
I am running windows 10

Comment: Okay, if you issue the command `python3 -m pip list` then does the package you want to use show up there? If not, then the `pip` command you issued before, is not "connected" to the `python3` interpreter that you're launching the script with.

Comment: Also, since you're running Windows, then you might also be able to use the "python launcher" to check what installation you have. You can try that by issuing the command: `py -0 --list` That should list all the installations that the launcher is aware of.

Comment: yeah, it's not showing so how do I fix that. I am a beginner so bear with me.

Comment: ```py -0 --list``` I tried this it gives me NameError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're having issues with is that your `pip` command, is not connected to your installation of `python3`.

If you're using Windows, then you should have a "python launcher" that you can use to double-check your installed versions of Python like this:

```
PS C:\> py -0
Installed Pythons found by C:\windows\py.exe Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64 *
 -3.7-32
```

Here you can see that I have two versions of Python installed on my device. So, let's check what both of those installations has installed using their own versions of `pip`.

Let's start with my `3.7` installation:

```
PS C:\> py -3.7 -m pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
beautifulsoup4     4.8.1
Jinja2             2.11.2
keyring            21.2.0
```

Here we can see that I have three packages installed.

Now let's check my `3.9` installation:

```
PS C:\> py -3.9 -m pip list
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- ---------
matplotlib                       3.4.1
numpy                            1.19.4
pandas                           1.1.5
pip                              21.0.1
```

What I am doing above basically, is calling the different `python` installations, and opening it with the following flag:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

The `pip` command is basically just an alias for `<python-installation> -m pip`, so when I issue the above command, I am launching `pip` with a specific python-installation.

---

If you do not have the "python-launcher" that I have in my above examples, but you have different aliases for your python-interpreters, then you can issue the same commands in the same way, just using your aliases.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
# will show you the installed packages for the alias "python2"
python2 -m pip list

# will show you the installed packages for the alias "python3"
python3 -m pip list
```

And you can obviously issue other commands to `pip` using that same logic, so if you want to install a package for a specific version you can do something like:

```
# will try to install the given package for the alias "python3"
python3 -m pip install <nameOfPackage>
```

Comment: I actually searched for another installed version of python on my PC but I found nothing. Thank you for helping me but this isn't the cause of the problem. However, I tried running this ```python3 -m pip list``` and it only showed me numpy. what does this mean?

Comment: It means that the only package installed on your `python3` installation is `numpy`. Because you have another `pip` that doesn't hold the same installed packages as the one you're working with, then there 100% is another installation of python on your device somewhere, that is the "owner" of the pip-command in your PATH. If you want to install your package inside of `python3` then just issue this command: `python3 -m pip install PyDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir you were totally right about the other existing PIP. I don't know why but just adding ```python3 -m``` to ```PIP install PyDictionary``` made it work. Maybe, my PC was assigning that PIP to another version of python not python3.

Comment: No problems man. If your question has been answered, don't hesitate accept my answer to make the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Type this

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Make sure you include the empty spaces.
Then:

`C:/Python36/Scripts/pip install Pydictionary`

Notes:
You are installing the PyDictionary for a specific python version to see what version of python you have installed on the terminal, type py and press enter
then type your version on the Python36 ... make sure you use the capital letter on the name Python, Scripts...I had the same problem and I installed the python27 version.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Worked for me